# Hotchocolate logging errors with a scoped service

Tags: c#, hotchocolate

So I'm trying to log errors with `HotChocolate 12.5.2` and I want to know the best place to intercept the errors. Reading the hotchocolate Documentation I found that the interface `IErrorFilter` have a `OnError` method that is called every time an error occurs, but its implementation is singleton. Is there somewhere where the service is scoped that I can intercept this error, or is there a way to inject my Scoped service in a to log the error?

I can intercept and personalize my error but I cant inject my service. I just want to know if this is the best place to intercept the error and if is the best pratice to log errors here.

This is what I'm trying:

```
    public class CustomErrorFilter : IErrorFilter
    {
        private readonly IBaseService _service;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

        public CustomErrorFilter(IBaseService service, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _service = service;
            _accessor = accessor;
        }

        public IError OnError(IError error)
        {
            if (error.Exception is not null)
                return error.WithMessage(error.Exception.Message);

            _service.Add<Log, LogViewModel>(new LogViewModel()
            {
                Message= error.Message,
            }, _accessor.HttpContext.User);

            return error;
        }
    }
```

`IBaseService` is my generic class that access my application `DbContext` and is a Scoped service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try injecting `IServiceScopeFactory` instead your scoped dependency and create scope and resolve dependency in `OnError` handler:

```cs
public class CustomErrorFilter : IErrorFilter
{
   private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory; 
   //...
   public CustomErrorFilter(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
   {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        _accessor = accessor;
   }

   public IError OnError(IError error)
   {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBaseService>(); 
            // use service
        }
   }
}
```